# How to remove "navigation dots" added from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, image, slider

I want to use this slider on my website

http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/FullWidthImageSlider/ - Demo
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/02/26/full-width-image-slider/ - Info 
http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/FullWidthImageSlider/FullWidthImageSlider.zip - source files

But I want to remove the navigation dots and keep the arrows only
[image: full slider]

How to do that?
I tried to find them in the index.html file, but obviosly they are somehow coded in the JS...

Thanks

---- EDITED ----

I think this code, placed in jquery.cbpFWSlider.js do this job. When I remove few lines of it it removes the dots, but the slider stop working

```
// add navigation arrows (the previous arrow is not shown initially):
                this.$navPrev = $( '<span class="cbp-fwprev">&lt;</span>' ).hide();
                this.$navNext = $( '<span class="cbp-fwnext">&gt;</span>' );
                $( '<nav/>' ).append( this.$navPrev, this.$navNext ).appendTo( this.$el );
                // add navigation dots
                var dots = '';
                for( var i = 0; i < this.itemsCount; ++i ) {
                    // current dot will have the class cbp-fwcurrent
                    var dot = i === this.current ? '<span class="cbp-fwcurrent"></span>' : '<span></span>';
                    dots += dot;
                }
                var navDots = $( '<div class="cbp-fwdots"/>' ).append( dots ).appendTo( this.$el );
                this.$navDots = navDots.children( 'span' );

            }
```

---- UPDATE ----

`dots += dot;`

removing this line from the js file, did the trick. But is it safe?

Comment: @Third edit There should also be some code that keeps the dots and the images shown synchronized (some click handlers probably and some code to change the classes on the spans). You should make sure that none of them breaks when the expected spans aren't in the document anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS:

```
.cbp-fwdots { 
  display:none;
}
```

If you somehow changed the classes on the slider, you need to use Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools or some other tool to find it. The class i mentioned is placed in your demo on the container of the dots.

Comment: ok, this is the last option, but the browser will still render "the dots", isnt it?

I mean it will take time, resources and is bad for the PageSpeed

Comment: Hardly. The dots are just some empty spans styled to look like bullets. While yes, they aren't free to create, they certainly aren't expensive, so leaving them in takes significantly less time than for example reducing the size(quality) of your images by a small factor.